# Activity and service both gets different value of Application instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

Hi I have created one static variable in Application Class.
I am also accessing only Singleton class.
but I am getting different value of that variable in `Activity` and `Service`.

Code.
MyApplication Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public static int activeRouteId;
private static MyApplication mInstance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        //ACRA.init(this);
        mInstance=this;

        activeRouteId=PreferenceHelper.getActiveRouteId(mInstance);

    }
    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

When i try to use in `Fragment`

```
 MyApplication.activeRouteId=2
```

but at the same time it shows -1 value while using from service.

I am changing value of this variable from Fragment.

Comment: Why are you extending `Application` just for this? It looks like `PreferenceHelper.getActiveRouteId(...)` is static anyway so why don't you just call it directly from anywhere you need it.

Comment: I have used UniversalImageLoader,acra and volley also. so to avoid reading from preference i am accessing Static variable inside application.